# The sequence $(u'_n)$, with $u_n$ the regularization of $u$, converges a.e to $u'$ on a compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convolution

Let be $u:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a convex function.
I consider $u_n=u*\rho_n$, defined on $\mathbb{R}$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$,

where $\rho_\epsilon(x)=\epsilon^{-n}\rho(\dfrac{x}{n})$ (the standard mollifier) and 
$$\rho(x) = \begin{cases} e^{1/(1-|x|^2)}/I& \text{ if } |x| < 1\\
                 0& \text{ if } |x|\geq 1
                 \end{cases},$$
( $I$ is a coefficient of normalization).

Let be $R>0$. I know that the sequence $(u_n)$ converges uniformly to $u$ in $[0,R]$.

> - Is it true that the sequence of the derivative $(u'_n)$ converges almost everywhere to $u'$ in $[0,R]$?
>     I think that the answer is yes, but I can't find a reference.
> - Can I say something about the convergenge of $(u''_n)$?
>     Is it true that  $(u''_n)$ converges almost everywhere to $u''$?

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Note that $u' \ast \rho_n = u \ast \rho_n' = (u\ast \rho_n)'$.

Comment: Because $u$ is convex, it admits a right derivative $u'_+(x)$ and a left derivative $u'_-(x)$ at each  $x\in\Bbb R$. Both $u'_+$ and $u'_-$ are non-decreasing; $u'_+$ is right continuous and $u'_-$ is left continuous, and  $u'_-(x)\le u'_+(x)$ for all $x$, with equality except for those $x$ where either (equivalently, both) $u'_+$ or $u'_-$ has a jump. Therefore $\lim_nu'_n(x)$ exists for all $x$ and equals $u'(x)$ if $u'$ is continuous at $x$; and equals $[u'_-(x)+u'_+(x)]/2$ if $u'_+$ has a jump at $x$.